# How to create React components from a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, forms

I want to create some form components using React. I know how to do that using pure JavaScript by `createElement()` and such methods, not sure how would I go about this in React.

My JSON array would look like:

```
[{
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "hiddenInput",
    "id": "hiddenInput",
    "type": "hidden",
    "label": "Hidden Label"
},{
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "textInput",
    "id": "textInput",
    "type": "text",
    "label": "Text Label"
}, {
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "passwordInput",
    "id": "passwordInput",
    "type": "password",
    "label": "Password Label"
}, {
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "emailInput",
    "id": "emailInput",
    "type": "email",
    "label": "Email Label"
}, {
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "phoneInput",
    "id": "phoneInput",
    "type": "text",
    "label": "Phone Label"
}, {
    "tag": "textarea",
    "name": "textarea",
    "id": "textarea",
    "label": "Textarea Label"
}, {
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "dateInput",
    "id": "dateInput",
    "type": "date",
    "label": "Date Label"
}, {
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "checkboxInput",
    "id": "checkboxInput",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "label": "Checkbox Label"
}, {
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "radioInput",
    "id": "radioInput",
    "type": "radio",
    "label": "Radio Label"
},{
    "tag": "button",
    "name": "buttonInput",
    "id": "buttonInput",
    "type": "button",
    "label": "Submit"
}];
```

and my desired output would be similar to:

```
  render() {
    return (
        <Form onSubmitStart={this.props.onSubmitStart}>
          <Input
            name="hiddenInput"
            id="hiddenInput"
            type="hidden"
            label="Hidden Label"
            value={this.state.hiddenInput}
          />

          <Input
            name="textInput"
            id="textInput"
            type="text"
            label="Text Label"
          />

          <Input
            name="passwordInput"
            id="passwordInput"
            type="password"
            label="Password Label"
          />

          <Input
            name="emailInput"
            id="emailInput"
            type="email"
            label="Email Label"
          />

          <PhoneInput
            name="phoneInput"
            id="phoneInput"
            type="text"
            country={"us"}
            enableAreaCodes={true}
            onlyCountries={["us"]}
            areaCodes={{ us: ["999","888"] }}
            inputProps={{
              name: "phone",
              country: "us",
              required: true,
              autoFocus: true
            }}
            value={this.state.phone}
            onChange={this.handlePhoneInput}
          />

        <textarea 
            name="dateInput"
            id="dateInput"
            rows={this.state.rows}
            cols={this.state.cols}
            >
        </textarea>

          <Input
            name="dateInput"
            id="dateInput"
            type="date"
            label="Date Label"
            onChange={this.handleDateInput}
          />

          <Checkbox
            name="checkboxInput"
            id="checkboxInput"
            type="checkbox"
            label="Checkbox Label"
            checked={this.state.checkbox}
          />

          <Radio
            name="radioInput"
            id="radioInput"
            type="radio"
            label="Radio Label"
            value={this.state.radio}
          />

          <Button 
            name="buttonInput"
            id="buttonInput"
            type="button"
            label="Button Label"
           > Submit </Button>
        </Form>
    );
  }
```

How would I do that?

#### Articles

[JSON based dynamic forms with ReactJS](https://medium.com/curofy-engineering/dynamic-forms-with-react-js-d25d7c4f53d1)

[How To Create React.js Components Dynamically](http://react.tips/how-to-create-reactjs-components-dynamically/)

(Thanks! I'm new to React framework.)

Comment: perhaps [this one](https://dev.to/idiglove/create-custom-components-from-json-with-react-1oeb) is closer to what you want

Comment: You can always use plain Javascript instead of JSX. Remember that JSX gets transpiled to sentences with a signature like`React.createElement(<type>, <props>, <children>)`.

Comment: When I said "plain Javascript", I mean React without JSX. but the accepted answer is a really good solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map over the elements and return the appropriate element for each:

```js
const data = [{
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "hiddenInput",
    "id": "hiddenInput",
    "type": "hidden",
    "label": "Hidden Label"
},{
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "textInput",
    "id": "textInput",
    "type": "text",
    "label": "Text Label"
}, {
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "passwordInput",
    "id": "passwordInput",
    "type": "password",
    "label": "Password Label"
}, {
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "emailInput",
    "id": "emailInput",
    "type": "email",
    "label": "Email Label"
}, {
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "phoneInput",
    "id": "phoneInput",
    "type": "text",
    "label": "Phone Label"
}, {
    "tag": "textarea",
    "name": "textarea",
    "id": "textarea",
    "label": "Textarea Label"
}, {
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "dateInput",
    "id": "dateInput",
    "type": "date",
    "label": "Date Label"
}, {
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "checkboxInput",
    "id": "checkboxInput",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "label": "Checkbox Label"
}, {
    "tag": "input",
    "name": "radioInput",
    "id": "radioInput",
    "type": "radio",
    "label": "Radio Label"
},{
    "tag": "button",
    "name": "buttonInput",
    "id": "buttonInput",
    "type": "button",
    "label": "Submit"
}];

function Form ({data}) {
  return (
    <form>
      {data.map(({tag: Cmp, ...other}) => (
        <div key={other.id}>
          {other.label}: <Cmp {...other} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form data={data}/>, document.getElementById('demo'));
```

```css
form > * {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"/>
```

Comment: Updated to show the correct labels. You'd have to tweak it to get the label into the text of the button, but that should be trivial.

Comment: If you wanted to do something a bit more sophisticated and customize the way each type renders, you could have a mapping that chooses the appropriate react component for each entry, based on 'tag' and/or 'type'. Those components could then render whatever they want, not just a plain html input or textarea, etc.